# get input Text from JTextField (string to char) to show up in JButton

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

(new rewritten code).. I just know that "b" will always the last box that i created.So i can't use b as the equals in actionPerformed. How to include all the buttons?  Anyone can help me with this?
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

```
public class Lat1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    final int ROWS = 12;

    final int COLS = 12;

    final static int topLeftNum[][]= {
        {-1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, -1, 4, 0, 5, 0},
        {6, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1},
        {-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 7, 0, 0, 8, -1, 0, -1},
        {9, 0, 0, 0, 10, -1, -1, -1, 11, 0, 0, -1},
        {0, -1, -1, 12, 0, 0, 13, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1},
        {0, -1, 14, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 15, 0, 0, 16},
        {17, 0, 0, 18, 0, -1, 19, 20, 0, -1, -1, 0},
        {0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 21, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0},
        {22, 23, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1,24, 0, 0},
        {-1, 0, -1, 25, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1},
        {26, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 27, 0, 0, 0, -1},
        {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1}
        };

     Box b;

     JTextField t;

     char answer;

     public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {

            public void run(){  new Lat1(); }
        });
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
    public Lat1() 
    {   

    this.setSize(1000,1000);
    this.setVisible(true);
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();   
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS,COLS));
        for (int j=0; j<ROWS; j++) {
            for (int i=0; i<COLS; i++)  {
                b = new Box(i, //the boxes index
                (topLeftNum[j][i] < 0) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE, //pick the color
                topLeftNum[j][i], //the topleft number
                answer, //the char inside
                this); //the action listener for the button
                p1.add(b);
            }
        }
        p1.setVisible(true);
        this.getContentPane().add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.pack();

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        t = new JTextField(10);
        p2.add(t);
        p2.setVisible(true);
        this.getContentPane().add(p2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    for (int j=0; j<ROWS; j++) {
        for (int i=0; i<COLS; i++)  {
    String numstr = String.valueOf(topLeftNum[j][i]);       
    if(e.getSource() == numstr && (t.getText()).length() == 1)
    answer = t.getText().charAt(0);
    b.setText(""+ answer);

    //b.setText(String.valueOf(t.getText().charAt(0));
        }
    }
}   
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------*/

class Box extends JButton

{

    public int index;

    private String topLeftNum;

    public Box(int index, Color color, int topLeftNum, char c, ActionListener al) 

    {


    this.setBackground(color);

        if (color != Color.BLACK) {

            this.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.ITALIC, 20));

            this.setText(""+ c);

            this.addActionListener(al);

            this.index = index;

            if (topLeftNum != 0)

            this.topLeftNum = topLeftNum+"";    }

        else {

            this.setText("");

            this.setEnabled(false);

            return; }

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 

    {

    super.paintComponent(g); // paints background

    g.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 8));

        if (topLeftNum != null) g.drawString(topLeftNum, 5, 10);

    }

}
/*----------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You have **NullPointerException** thrown at line 59 from constructor of main class. You attempt to **getText** from field which is not initialized.

Secondly You can call **repaint** method, so label changing code might look as follows:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
    Field f = (Field)e.getSource();
    Box b = f.box;
    b.setText(f.getText());
    b.repaint();
    this.remove(f);
    this.add(f.box, b.index);
  }
}
```

This should probably force JButton to change its look.

*(Advice for Your next posts: add indentation to Your code, please)*

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll be sure to remember that. I have initialized the field by putting "Field f;" or am i wrong?

Comment: Initialized means creating an instance of a Field class and assigning it to f, e.g. Field f = new Field(new Box(...), this);

Comment: So, i should have put " Field f = new Field(); "? But then,  i got an error again. "Cannot resolve symbol constructor Field() loaction class field"

Comment: where do i have to put the initialization Field on? more detail if you wouldn't mind.

Comment: Field constructor is public Field(Box box, KeyListener kl), so You cannot write Field f = new Field(); You have to give arguments, in this case: Box instance, and KeyListener.

Initializations can be placed where the variable declaration is or in contructor of Lat1 class.

Comment: in the Box instance(argument) there is int,color,int,char,actionlistner. What should i replace the char with? (If i want to getText from Field f and make it show up on JTable)?

Comment: Char may be replaced with anything. The real problem is a design of Your classes. I suggest You to rewrite whole program.

Comment: Ok.. i think i'll rewrite again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an ActionListener and not a KeyListener. Although it is not the cuase of your problem it is the better design when using a JTextField.

Comment: and what do i use for the if-else? e.g. String s = e.getActionCommand(); if(s.equalas("???")) What should i replace the "???" with? The JButton doesn't even have name on it (e.g. main = new Button("main").

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually add the TextField to anything as far as I can tell either - and your processing inside actionPerformed fails to compile due to a mismatch between Object (the class returned by "e.getSource()" and int (your "b.index" value).

Also, "b" is always the last "box" you create. You're a long way from a solution here.

Comment: Is there a way to add the TextField without messing the gridLayout?? Because i already set the GridLayout to COLS and ROWS.

Comment: make another panel with a different Layout (for now, try something simple like BorderLayout); add your existing panel to it as the CENTER component; add the textfield as SOUTH, stick this new panel in the jframe instead of your existing one, then try it out and see what happens.

Comment: now my only problem is the buttons(Box). How can i make it so only the white buttons works? If i can't use b, then what should i use?

Answer (score -1):

repainting will work, but i recommend calling

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(b);
```

that will refresh the entire component plus any children.

N

Comment: -1 updateComponentTreeUI(...) is for LAF changes and should not be used just because you don't know what the underlying problem is.

Comment: Because i am not familiar with it, so i do not use it.

Comment: my bad. while this will work, it's not the correct way to do it.